# how to map a new controller with a directory to get views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new to asp.net MVC ,
i have created a new controller name "PersonController.cs" and a new view folder "Person" ,
now the problem is person controller searching view only in "Home" and "Shared" directory not in Person Directory any answer?

Error : The view 'Reject' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Reject.aspx
~/Views/Home/Reject.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Reject.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Reject.ascx

Answer (score 1):

Your link in the view your wanting to navigate from:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Person Link", "Reject", "Person") %>
```

Your PersonController:

```
public ActionResult Reject()
{
    return View("Reject");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something like this in your Global.asax file (usually called in RegisterRoutes):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Also you must have an action named Reject in the Person cotroller.